# Is there any limit to the length of text content that a PowerShell variable can hold?

Tags: powershell

I am storing the content of a text file in a variable like this -

```
$fileContent=$(Get-Content file1.txt)
```

Right now file1.txt contains 200 lines only. But if one day the file contains 10 million lines, then will this approach work? Is there any limit to the length of content that a variable can hold in PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Content` reads the file into memory.

With that being said, you'd want to change the approach on what you're after. PowerShell being built on top of the .Net framework has access to all of its capabilities. So, you can use classes such as [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-7.0) which reads the file from disk one line at a time using a method like the one below.

```
$file = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new('.\Desktop\adobe_export.reg') #instantiate an istance of streamreader
while ($file.EndOfStream.Equals($false)) #if not end of file, continue.
{
    # save this to a variable if needed
    $file.ReadLine() # read/display line
    # more code
}
$file.Close()
$file.Dispose()
```

Comment: "Get-Content reads the file into memory" - this is true, but [it reads it line by line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2#description), so your soultion can just be turned into `Get-Content file1.txt | [code to manipulate one line]`, because the pipeline receives only one line at a time and only that much memory is used for the items in the pipeline.
@MVKXXX You need to reconsider why you would need to load the entire thing into memory. You don't have to assign cmdlet outputs to variables, just use the pipeline.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó, good point. May I suggest you post an answer explaining that, or give me some time before I'm on my computer again and I'll update it accordingly. ty

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand that [a PS variable is a wrapper around a .NET type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7.2#types-of-variables), so whatever that can hold, is the answer.
Regarding your actual case, you can search in Microsoft docs whatever `GetType()` returns, if there is a limit for that type - but there is always a memory limit. So if you read a lot of data into memory, and then return some of it after filtering/transforming/completing/whatever, you are filling memory. Instead you may NOT assign anything to a variable, but use [the pipeline's one-at-a-time processing functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.2#one-at-a-time-processing), with this only that much memory is used for the items in the pipeline. Of course you might need to do more than one complex thing with the same input that need their own pipelines, but in this case you can either re-read the data, or if you think that it can change between reads and you need a snapshot, then copy it into a temporary place.